# Efficient way to compute Eulers Totient Function for big input

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

Based on wikipedias description about [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), i wrote the following code:

```
from math import gcd

def phi(n):
    amount = 0
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        if gcd(n, k) == 1:
            amount += 1
    return amount
```

It works fine for small numbers, but i want to compute the totient function for numbers such as
n = 5692297035794675412610596123456169

Is there any better way to compute the Totoent function for such as big inputs?

Comment: You need to use some maths. Brute force is not enough.

Comment: If this is RSA and your large number is N = p*q where p and q are primes, then there is a very simple way to calculate totient(N).  A little research will help you.

Comment: Big? how big? `factor(5692297035794675412610596123456169)` and `phi = (47-1) * (2819-1) * (65713-1) * (891551-1) * (57247819-1) * (12809677289-1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing Eulers Totient Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114138/computing-eulers-totient-function)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_product_formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is also tagged Cryptography, this about more into the effectiveness of possible algorithms.

There is a way to compute the Euler Totient φ **very fast** if you know the prime factors of `n`. Let p<sub>i</sub> be distinct `k` primes factors of `n` then

φ(n) = (p<sub>1</sub> -1) * (p<sub>2</sub>-1) * ... * (p<sub>k</sub>-1)

There is also a formula for prime powers, too. That is not necessary here since either RSA encryption/signature or Paillier encryption or Rabin signatures uses `n = p*q` with two distinct primes `p` and `q`.

As we see, effectively finding the φ(n) requires the knowledge of the factorization. It is proven that for RSA the knowledge of the φ(n) is equal to factorization of the `n`. Shortly see here;

- [Why is it important that phi(n) is kept a secret, in RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75709/18298)

or see in the original RSA paper;

- [A Method for Obtaining Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystems](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf)

If we turn to factoring (RSA), the current record achieved in 2020, [CADO-NFS](https://gitlab.inria.fr/cado-nfs) has [factored](https://caramba.loria.fr/rsa250.txt) an [828-bit n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-250) with "roughly 2700 core-years, using Intel Xeon Gold 6130 CPUs as a reference (2.1GHz)".

However, if you ever need to use RSA, you should use a modulus of size at least 2048-bits, see in [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/). This is safe from factoring at least for a reasonable time from classical factorization and Shor's quantum factoring algorithm.

As a result, **there is no effective algorithm for finding the Euler's totient for large `n` if you don't know the factorization.**