# Prime Number Generating Puzzle (Edge Cases)

Tags: python, primes

I'm solving the following problem on a coding site. It's failing for some edge cases on the tests (hidden tests), but I'm not sure what they are. Anyone see any issues with this?

Problem: Let `A` be a string of all the prime numbers sequentially squashed together (i.e. `235711131719...`). Given an index `n`, return a string of 5 digits where the first digit is at index `n` in A.

e.g. `foo(0) => 23571` and `foo(10) => 19232`

Here's my code:

```
def gen_primes():                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    A = {}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    i = 2                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    while True:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        if i not in A:                                                                                                                                                                                               
            yield i                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            A[i * i] = [i]                                                                                                                                                                                           
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            for p in A[i]:                                                                                                                                                                                           
                A.setdefault(p + i, []).append(p)                                                                                                                                                                    
            del A[i]                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        i += 1                                                                                                                                                                                                       

def answer(n):                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    counter = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    prime_string = ""                                                                                                                                                                                                

    for p in gen_primes():                                                                                                                                                                                           
        if (counter >= n):
            prime_string += str(p)                                                                                                                                                                                   
        counter += len(str(p))                                                                                                                                                                                       
        if len(prime_string) >= 5:                                                                                                                                                                                   
            break                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    return prime_string[:5]
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Maybe it is slow for edge cases and the site you are using is running in "timeout"? There is a dedicated site for code reviews in so.

Comment: did my answer solve your question ?

Answer (score 3):

I think this could break for primes with more than one digit:

Let's assume that we have arrived at primes with three digits, like 103.
`Counter` is 10 and `n` is 11 (this is just an example, I don't know if this exact constellation would turn up)

Then we would need to use the digits "03" out of "103". But since `counter` is smaller than `n`, the entire prime is skipped. The program would continue with 107.

You could fix this by removing `counter` entirely: Always add primes to the string, break out of the loop if the length of the string is `n+5` or more.

EDIT:

I've checked your code: An example is `answer(5)` and `answer(6)`. With your code, both calls result in "13171". The second digit of "11" is skipped.

With this code:

```
def answer(n):                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    counter = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    prime_string = ""                                                                                                                                                                                                

    for p in gen_primes():
        prime_string += str(p)                                                                                                                                                                                     
        if len(prime_string) >= n+5:                                                                                                                                                                                   
            break                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    return prime_string[n:n+5]
```

They result in

```
11317  # answer(5)
13171  # answer(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer; it is similar to that of @lhk, but uses a sliding window instead of storing the entire string:

```
phil@haydn ~ $ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 17 2013, 15:31:50) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def primegen(): # http://stackoverflow.com/a/20660551
...     yield 2; yield 3          # prime (!) the pump
...     ps = primegen()           # sieving primes
...     p = next(ps) and next(ps) # first sieving prime
...     D, q, c = {}, p*p, p      # initialize
...     def add(x, s):            # insert multiple/stride
...         while x in D: x += s  #   find unused multiple
...         D[x] = s              #   save multiple/stride
...     while True:               # infinite list
...         c += 2                # next odd candidate
...         if c in D:            # c is composite
...             s = D.pop(c)      #   fetch stride
...             add(c+s, s)       #   add next multiple
...         elif c < q: yield c   # c is prime; yield it
...         else: # (c == q)      # add sqrt(c) to sieve
...             add(c+p+p, p+p)   #   insert in sieve
...             p = next(ps)      #   next sieving prime
...             q = p * p         #   ... and its square
... 
>>> def primeSubstr(n): # nth character in concatenated primes
...     ps = primegen()           # sequence of prime numbers
...     i, s = 0, ''              # current index, sliding window
...     while True:               # do ... until i == n
...         if len(s) < 5:        # sliding window too small
...             s+=str(next(ps))  #   add next prime to window
...         elif i < n:           # not yet to target index
...             i, s = i+1, s[1:] #   slide window to right
...         else: return s[:5]    # return desired substring
... 
>>> primeSubstr(0)
'23571'
>>> primeSubstr(5)
'11317'
>>> primeSubstr(10)
'19232'
>>> primeSubstr(15)
'93137'
>>> primeSubstr(20)
'41434'
>>> primeSubstr(1000)
'98719'
>>> CTRL-D
```

I will discuss this problem tomorrow at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2017/01/10/prime-string/).

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a job for [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html), how about this

```
>>> from sympy import sieve
>>> from itertools import islice, chain
>>> def primeSubStr(n):
        primes=iter(sieve)
        next(primes)
        return "".join( islice( chain.from_iterable(map(str,primes)), n, n+5))

>>> primeSubStr(0)
'23571'
>>> primeSubStr(10)
'19232'
>>> primeSubStr(5)
'11317'
>>> primeSubStr(15)
'93137'
>>> primeSubStr(20)
'41434'
>>> primeSubStr(1000)
'98719'
>>> primeSubStr(2000)
'98940'
>>>
```

For simplicity I use sympy.sieve to get the prime numbers, but any method of getting the primes would work just fine, like the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2211990/5644961) for instance.

Now the interesting part, the map is obvious enough, with that we get a stream of `"2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13", ... "101", "103", ...` then with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) that stream is discomposed in a stream of singles digit `"2", "3", "5", "7", "1","1", "1","3", ... "1","0","1", "1","0","3", ...` and finally with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) we take the part we want and join it for the final result