# How to find all factors of a huge number which is of only a few factors in less than 1 second?

Tags: python, performance, numbers

For example, the number is 3000000021 whose prime factors are 3 and 1000000007.

In a traditional way, e.g.

```
n=int(raw_input())
d=2
factors=[]
while n!=1:
    if n%d==0:
        factors.append(d)
        n/=d
    else:
        d+=1
print factors
```

It takes forever to analyze such number.

Pollard's Rho algorithm seems to be a good solution in this case, but it can't get all of them. Is there any faster way to solve this problem?

Comment: [This link should solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python)

Comment: This seems like a pretty standard problem; did you look *anywhere* for a solution?

Comment: You could start by not testing every even integer greater than 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way of finding all the factors of a number in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python)

Comment: an approach using `bitarray`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31122596/4954037

Comment: Are you just wanting prime factors or all factors?

Answer (score 0):

Even a very simple `factors()` function which has a simple optimisation of limiting to `sqrt(n)+1`, completes in sub `1s`

```
In [1]:
def factors(n):
    for a in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % a:
            continue
        yield from {a, n//a}

In [2]:
list(factors(3000000021))

Out[2]:
[3, 1000000007]

In [3]:
%timeit list(factors(3000000021))

Out[3]:
100 loops, best of 3: 6.69 ms per loop
```

If you only need prime factors then you need an efficient prime number generator (lots of examples can be found on SO) then:

```
In [4]:
def pfactors(n):
    for p in primes():
        while n % p == 0:
            yield p
            n //= p
        if p*p > n:
            if n > 1:
                yield n
            break

list(pfactors(3000000021))

Out[4]:
[3, 1000000007]
```

The speed of this is dependent on your prime number generator. For my python prime number generator:

```
In [5]:
%timeit list(pfactors(3000000021))

Out[5]:
100 loops, best of 3: 6.13 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

credit goes to Evgeni Sergeev

```
from sympy import factorint
factorint(3000000021)

#output
{3: 1, 1000000007: 1}
```

factorint returns a dictionary where you can get all the prime factors by

```
list(factorint(3000000021).keys())
#Prime factors of 3000000021:
[3, 1000000007]
```

each key shows the prime factor while each value shows the power of corresponding prime factor in dictionary