# How to get a prime collection within 2^63 - 1 in Python

Tags: python, arrays, primes

I want to get a prime number set within 2^63 - 1 in Python,I have seen the following code on the web:

```
limit = 2**63 - 2
p = [True] * (limit + 1)
# p = bitarray(limit + 1)
p[0] = p[1] = False
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(limit) + 1)):
    if p[i]:
        for j in range(i * i, limit + 1, i):
            p[j] = False
prime = [i for i in range(limit + 1) if p[i]]
print(prime)
```

But when I run this program, the compiler complains that `can not fit 'int' into an index-sized integer`.
I tried to solve the problem with bitarray, but the index of the array is still too big.

Comment: Added `import math` as first line and set a lower limit (e.g. 100) ... then the program works perfectly. With `limit = 2 ** 63 - 1` I'm getting a MemoryError ...

Comment: This looks like the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  It's super quick, but very memory hungry.  Generating primes up to 2^63 would take millions of Gigabytes of memory using the naive implementation.

Comment: what does "within 2^63-1" mean? There are too many primes < 2^63 to enumerate all of them with current technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. It is using the Sieve of Eratosthenes in combination with a generator function in order to reduce the memory usage of this algorithm. It is furthermore exploiting the less commonly known fact that every prim number > 4 can be written as 6*n ± 1.

```
import math

limit = 2 ** 63 - 1

def isPrim(n, belowPrims):
    limit = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for prim in belowPrims:
        if prim > limit: break
        if n % prim == 0: return False 
    return True

def calcPrims():
    yield 2
    yield 3
    toTest, nextN = [], 6
    while True:
        p1 = nextN - 1
        if isPrim(p1, toTest):
            yield p1
            toTest.append(p1)
        p2 = nextN + 1
        if isPrim(p2, toTest):
            yield p2
            toTest.append(p2)
        nextN += 6

for prim in calcPrims():
    if prim > limit:
        break
    print(prim)
```

**Edit**

This link here https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html explains briefly why every prim number can be written in the form 6*n ± 1.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Oh f**k you are right, the correct limit is 3 not 2. I updated the code accordingly. .. In case someone is interested why every prim number can be written in the form 6n+-1, this link here explains it briefly https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html

Comment: Add the link to your answer - I dont tell if you dont tell about the `3`

Comment: @quant Please use better language here.

Comment: If I want to generate a prime number set between 5e9 and 2 ** 63 - 1, how should your code be modified?

Comment: @fanfei The Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm requires you to know the prim numbers between 0 and 5e9 in order to calculate the prim numbers above. So there is no shortcut by not calculating these prim numbers. However you can modify the line `print(prim)` to `if prim < 5e9: print(prim)` in order to stop outputting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sympy:

```
import sympy

print(list(sympy.primerange(0,2**63-1)))
```

but as 2^63 is quite large this will take some time.

Comment: How long you think it will take to compute and print that list 216289611853439384 integers?

Comment: Longer than anyone would be able to wait, not to mention the amount of memory you would need.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a `primes()` generator of some kind, you could do this:

```
is_prime_var = 0

MAX = 1 << 5
last_p = 0
for p in primes():
    if p > MAX:
        break
    print(p, p-last_p)
    is_prime_var <<= (p - last_p)
    is_prime_var |= 1
    last_p = p
is_prime_var <<= (MAX - last_p - 1)
```

now the locations of the primes are stored (in reversed order) in the integer `is_prime_var`.

then the expression `(is_prime >> (MAX-n-1)) & 1` would be `1` if `n` is prime; `0` otherwise:

```
def is_prime(n):
    return bool((is_prime_var >> (MAX-n-1)) & 1)
```

you could use `primes()` from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563958/4954037) as prime generator.

thers is also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31122596/4954037) about a fast and memory-efficient sieve of eratosthenes. might also be interesting.