# Fastest Solution For Largest Prime Factor

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Is there a faster way to find the prime factors of 600851475143?

My computer still has not been able to produce an answer. Here's my code:

```
import sympy
num = 600851475143
list(filter(lambda x: sympy.isprime(x) and num % x ==0,range(2,600851475143 +1))
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31120986/4954037 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553925/adding-wheel-factorization-to-an-indefinite-sieve/30563958#30563958 and many more...

Comment: I think that there are more resources about this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: basically: compute primes up to sqrt(num), test divisors, then test if prime or if _other_ divisor is prime.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. I need a faster solution than mine as I still have not seen the solution on my computer

Answer (score 0):

This returns instantly:

```
In [17]: import sympy                                                                                                             

In [18]: sympy.factorint(600851475143)                                                                                            
Out[18]: {71: 1, 839: 1, 1471: 1, 6857: 1}
```

So

```
In [19]: max(sympy.factorint(600851475143))                                                                                       
Out[19]: 6857
```