# Sequential yield statements in a single method

Tags: python, generator

I know it never use to write several `return` statements sequentially bc the second one will be unreachable, eg:

```
def return_something():
    return 2
    return "Kolia" # unreachable
```

But if there any use to write several `yield` statement sequentially?

```
def yield_something():
    yield 3
    yield 4

print(next(yield_something()))
print(next(yield_something()))

>>> 3 
>>> 3
```

Seems to me I have seen somewhere use of sequential `yield` and my IDE doesn't highlighting it. Could anyone expose to me use of sequential `yield`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following exposes the use of the sequential yield in your example:

```
def yield_something():
    yield 3
    yield 4

a = yield_something()
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
```

**Output**

```
3
4
```

In your example, each time you call `yield_something()` you create a new generator. Create a generator using `a = yield_something()` and then use `next()` each time you want to `yield`.

Answer (score 4):

Sequential yield could be a replacement for, or replaced by, yielding the values in a constant tuple.

```
for i in (1,7,3,20):
    yield i

# versus

yield 1; yield 7; yield 3; yield 20
```

Alternatively, you might have more than one `yield` in your code, doing different things. I wouldn't consider these *sequential yields* so much as two parts of a larger function:

```
def unzip_dict(d):
    for k in d.keys():
        yield k
    for v in d.values():
        yield v
```

Answer (score 3):

You always create a new generator when using `yield_something()`. You should create one generator: `a = yield_something()` and then call `next(a)` on **that** generator:

```
def yield_something():
    yield 3
    yield 4

a = yield_something() # Generator
print(next(a)) # 3
print(next(a)) # 4
```

---

But generally you define a loop inside the generator that generates the `yields`:

```
def yield_something():
    for i in (3,4):
        yield i
```

or if they can be computed then the generator is really powerful because it doesn't need to keep the list of values in memory:

```
def yield_something():
    i = 3
    while i < 5:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are even real word examples. If you take a look at [this prime sieve implementation here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python), you see that it uses sequential yields. Although it's true it's used only as an optimization here.

The following code is copeid from tzot's answer:

```
import itertools as it
def erat3( ):
    D = { 9: 3, 25: 5 }
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield 5
    MASK= 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    MODULOS= frozenset( (1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29) )

    for q in it.compress(
            it.islice(it.count(7), 0, None, 2),
            it.cycle(MASK)):
        p = D.pop(q, None)
        if p is None:
            D[q*q] = q
            yield q
        else:
            x = q + 2*p
            while x in D or (x%30) not in MODULOS:
                x += 2*p
            D[x] = p
```