# Project Euler #37 issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to solve Project Euler #37:

> The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.
>   Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from left to right and right to left.
>   NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

I wrote my code in Python but I am facing weird issues.
Here's my code:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n == 2 or n == 3 or n == 5: return True
    if n < 2 or n%2 == 0: return False
    if n < 9: return True
    if n%3 == 0: return False
    if n%5 == 0: return False
    r = int(n**0.5)
    f = 5
    while f <= r:
      if n%f == 0: return False
      if n%(f+2) == 0: return False
      f +=6
    return True

def gen(nb):
    results = []
    nb_str = str(nb)
    for k in range(0, len(nb_str) - 1):
        results.append(nb_str[k:])
        results.append(nb_str[-k:])
    return results

def check(nb):
    for t in gen(nb):
        if not isPrime(int(t)):
            return False
    return True

c = 0
s = 0
i = 2
while c != 11:
    if check(i):
        c += 1
        s += i
    i += 1
print(s)
```

Where does the error come from? (The expected result is 748317)

I suspect the errors coming from the results list

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it

Comment: You've broken down your code into small, independently-usable functions, which is great—that means you can test those functions independently. Call `gen(nb)` on some numbers and see if you get the right results. If not, you've only got 6 lines of code to debug (and ask about on SO, if you get stuck) instead of the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe Iddon has explained the error in your code, but you can speed it up a little by turning `gen` into an actual generator. That way, you can stop checking the results for a given `nb` as soon as you detect a composite number (and `gen` will stop generating them). I've also made a few minor tweaks to your primality tester. Remember, the `or` operator short-circuits, so if `a` is True-ish in `a or b` then it doesn't bother evaluating `b`.

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n in {2, 3, 5, 7}:
        return True
    if n < 2 or n%2 == 0:
        return False
    if n%3 == 0 or n%5 == 0:
        return False
    r = int(n**0.5)
    f = 5
    while f <= r:
        if n%f == 0 or n%(f+2) == 0:
            return False
        f += 6
    return True

def gen(nb):
    yield nb
    nb_str = str(nb)
    for k in range(1, len(nb_str)):
        yield int(nb_str[k:])
        yield int(nb_str[:-k])

def check(nb):
    for t in gen(nb):
        if not isPrime(t):
            return False
    return True

c = s = 0
# Don't check single digit primes
i = 11
while c < 11:
    if check(i):
        c += 1
        s += i
        print(i)
    i += 2

print('sum', s)
```

**output**

```
23
37
53
73
313
317
373
797
3137
3797
739397
sum 748317
```

In fact, you can get rid of the `check` function, and replace it with `all`, which also short-circuits, like `or` does. So you can replace the

```
if check(i):
```

with

```
if all(map(isPrime, gen(i))):
```

Comment: If your talking about optimising the solution, then the most drastic improvement would be to use a prime sieve and memoize.

Comment: @JoeIddon Using my best prime sieve, sieving the odd numbers under 1000000 in a bytearray, is about 10 times faster than this solution. But I didn't post that version, since it deviates so much from the OP's. And using a fixed sieve is cheating a little, since you need to specify the sieve size. I guess I could use a progressive sieve in a dict, but that would chew up a lot more RAM.

Comment: Why would you have to use the progressive sieve in a dict? Just increase the size by like `10000` if you haven't found `11` yet.

Comment: @JoeIddon You could do that, but I don't like it because you have to copy the old array to the new one. Or maintain multiple arrays. I mentioned using dict because there's an interesting prime generator that does that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/4014959). (However, it's about twice as slow as my segmented sieve that uses bytearrays). But I guess a generator isn't so useful when you need random access to an indefinite sized set of primes. ;)

Comment: @JoeIddon Sorry if there's anything vague or confusing in my previous comment. It's 4:35AM here, and I may not be thinking straight. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link, really cool algorithm! I don't see your point about copying the lists though, you can just concat `[False] * 10000` to the old boolean list and then start crossing them off again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `gen()` function is not working correctly as your slicing is off, also, you count `2`, `3`, `5` and `7` as truncatable primes which the question denies.

The second slice should be the other way around:

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> for i in range(1,len(s)-1):
...     print(s[i:])
...     print(s[:-i])
... 
bcd
abc
cd
ab
```

which we can see produces the right strings.

---

Altogether then, the function should be:

```
def gen(nb):
    results = [nb]
    nb_str = str(nb)
    for k in range(1, len(nb_str)):
        results.append(int(nb_str[k:]))
        results.append(int(nb_str[:-k]))
    return results
```

*note I also added a string to int conversion - not sure how Python didn't make that obvious for you :/*

---

And before get the full solution, Project Euler nearly always gives you an example which you can use to check your code:

```
>>> check(3797)
True
```

You must also add a condition in the `check` function to return `False` if the number is `2`, `3`, `5` or `7` as this is stated clearly in the question.

---

And the result is the expected: `748317`.