# Prime factorization using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, factorization

How to write a function which returns a list of tuples like (c_i, k_i) for n such that n = c1^k1 * c2^k2 * ... , ci is a prime number.
For example: `12600 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7^1`
Desired output: `[(2, 3), (3, 2), (5, 2), (7, 1)]`
I know how to do it with `while` but **is it possible to do it using list comprehension?** Efficiency is not required in this task.

```
# naive function 
def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, n))

# while version
def factorization_while(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if is_prime(i):
            j = 0
            while n % i == 0:
                n = n // i
                j += 1
            if j != 0:
                res.append((i, j))
    return res

# list comprehension version
def factorization(n):
    return [
        (i, j) for i in range(1, n + 1) if is_prime(i) \
        and n % i == 0 ... # add smth
    ]
```

Comment: Squeezing everything into a single liner list comprehension is by no way a recommended way. There is a fine line between less verbose code and a long but readable/understandable code

Comment: @Bazingaa I know that it would be less readable but I just wanted to test myself if I was able to do it, and learn new things from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this should be too hard. You don't actually need to modify `n` to find its prime factors, they're all completely independent of each other. So just iterate through the appropriate primes, and find the maximum power that works!

```
from math import log

def prime_factors(n):
    return [(prime, max(power for power in range(1, int(log(n, prime))+1)
                              if n % prime**power == 0))
            for prime in range(2, n+1) if n % prime == 0 and isprime(prime)]
```

There are a few ways you might improve this further. You could use `itertools.takewhile` on an infinite generator of powers (e.g. `itertools.count`), as once you find the first power such that `prime**power` is not a factor of `n`, none of the later ones will be either. That would allow you to avoid the `log` call.

And there are a whole bunch of ways to efficiently iterate over the primes (see for instance, the very simple generator suggested [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119/), or higher performance versions that you can find in the answers to  [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python) [different questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) here on SO).