# Finding the largest prime factor of 13195

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem from the Project Euler archive: https://projecteuler.net/problem=3

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

I tried solving for 13195 first. My original idea was to create a list with all the prime numbers lower than the given number. I used the Sieve of Erathostenes algorithm to do this. Then, using a for loop I iterated through all those prime numbers adding the ones that are factors of the given number to a separate list. I sorted the list and printed the largest factor. When I ran the script I got one extra number in the factors list that was not a factor of the given number.

for `num = 13915` the output should have been [13, 29, 5, 7] but instead I got [13, 29, 377, 5, 7]

I wasn't able to figure out where 377 came from. I'm aware my solution is not the most efficient one but I tried solving this problem myself. So my questions are:

Where did 377 come from?
Can you suggest a more efficient way to solve this problem?

I apologize for any inconveniences as I'm new to problem solving in Python.

```
primes = []
num = 13195
factors = []
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    #sieve of erathostenes
    if i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0 and i % 7 != 0 and i != 1:
        primes.append(i)

if num >= 10:
    primes.append(2)
    primes.append(3)
    primes.append(5)
    primes.append(7)

sorted(primes)

for i in range(len(primes)):
    prime = primes[i]
    if num % prime == 0:
        factors.append(primes[i])


print(factors)
factors.sort()
print(factors[len(factors) - 1])
```

Comment: `sorted(primes)` doesn't do anything, because you don't assign the result to anything.

Comment: Finding *all* primes below a number in order to factor it seems like overkill. Also, `i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0 and i % 7 != 0` isn't a way to test if something is a prime. Note that `377 = 13*29`, but your code classifies it as a prime.

Comment: For more efficient ways to generate primes, we have two questions with really excellent answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to generate primes.  A direct factorisation of the number will be more efficient:

```
def primeFactors(N):  # generator for all prime factors
    p = 2
    while p*p<=N:       # only need up to √N (remaining N)
        while N%p == 0: # p is a factor (will be a prime)
            yield p     # return primes as many times as they appear
            N //= p     # remove the prime factor from the number
        p += 1 + p%2    # next potential prime
    if N>1: yield N     # beyond √N whatever remains is a prime factor
```

output:  (take the maximum factor found)

```
print(max(primeFactors(600851475143))) # 6857
```

Comment: You don't even need to take the max, since you're generating them in order.  The max should be the last one.

Comment: And I'm not sure the `while` loop is the best choice here, I might have used `for p in itertools.chain([2], range(3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(N)), 2))`

Comment: I agree that the function could be specialized to only return the last (maximum) factor.  The while loop however is useful because N decreases during the process (as we find factors) and this greatly reduces the number of iterations. A for loop would not allow for that unless we put in a break conditions, which would turn it into like a bastardized while loop.

Comment: Also, that chain trick would need to use chain.from_iterables otherwise it would create an internal list with all potential factors before proceeding . I've tried that in the past and there are faster solutions to step by two past prime 2. The insignificant speed differences made me keep the simplest form in the end.

Comment: I missed the fact that N was decreasing, forget I said anything.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the factors of a number sorted from largest to smallest

```
number = 13915
list_of_factors=sorted([int(number/n) for n in range(2,number//2 +1) if number % n ==0 ],reverse=True)
```

result is [2783, 1265, 605, 253, 121, 115, 55, 23, 11, 5]

Comment: For `600851475143` your comprehension would iterate over 300 billion possible `n`. To say that this isn't an efficient way to get `6857 (the largest prime factor)` is an understatement. Furthermore, you would still need to filter the returned list to discover which of the factors were prime.