# lazy computing of primes with python without recursion error

Tags: python, recursion, infinite-recursion

I came across this [great video from computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jwV3zxXc8E) which talked about lazy computing. In the video, they lay out this really beautiful bit of python code that will calculate primes using the sieve method "lazily"

```
def nats(n):
    yield n
    yield from nats(n+1)
def sieve(s): 
    n = next(s)
    yield n
    yield from sieve(i for i in s if i%n!=0)
```

The issue comes when you actually implement the code to calculate a large number of primes. Because you are recursively searching, the recursion depth is reached relatively quickly. I can only calculate a prime up to `2281`

If I modify the code to get rid of recursion with the first function:

```
def nats(n):
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1
```

Then I can get to prime `12379` before the recursion depth is reached.

If I understand the code correctly, you need recursion to keep inputting only digits that are prime candidates (via the sieve method) into the `sieve` function.

Is there a way to implement this "lazy computation" algorithm to do lazy computing without using recursion and thus calculating primes infinitely without running into recursion limit roadblocks?

Comment: There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621) implementation of a sieve which *does* use recursion, but only to a depth of 1.

Comment: Note: you can always [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration/) recursion into iteration.